# Optimization on hypergraph "refinements"

Tags: graphs, optimization, discrete-mathematics

Given a hypergraph $H = (V, E)$, call $H' = (V, E')$ a *refinement* of $H$ iff there exists a partition $p : E' \to I$ (where $I$ is an arbitrary index set) such that $E = \{\bigcup_{x \in p^{-1}(i)} x \mid i \in I\}$. Essentially this means that there's some way to partition the hyperedges in $E'$ such that merging together all the hyperedges in each part of the partition gives $E$. Note that this isn't quite the same as just splitting the edges in $E$, $(\{a, b, c\}, \{\{a, b\}, \{b, c\}\})$ would be a valid refinement of $(\{a, b, c\}, \{\{a, b, c\}\})$.

I made up this terminology, is there a name for this in the literature? It seems like a natural concept.

I'm particularly interested in solving a minimization problem where a weighted (i.e.: equipped with a function $w: E' \to \mathbb{N}$) hypergraph refinement is the variable, and the set of nodes in the hypergraph is weighted by a function $c: V \to \mathbb{N}$ that we'll call the *capacity* of a node. The only constraint is that the sum of the weights of the hyperedges incident on a given node must be less than or equal to its capacity. The objective function is $|E'| + |\{v \in V \mid L(v) > 0\}|$ where $L(v)$ is the "leftover weight", the difference between the capacity of $v$ and the sum of incident hyperedge weights, i.e.: $L(v) = c(v) - \Sigma_{e \in E', v \in e} w(e)$. The constraint is then formally stated as $L(v) \ge 0$ for all $v \in V$. Intuitively, this is like a combination of a minimum cover problem with a subset-sum on each node.

Is any of this secretly equivalent to something else?

For context, I'm trying to solve this problem where the hypergraph came from the maximal cliques of a graph (i.e.: we're really trying to find weights for each clique in a graph such that the sum of the incident cliques' weights is less than a per-node constant).

Comment: $E'$ isn't a partition -- it's a set of new hyperedges such that there _exists_ a partition of the hyperedges where merging all the hyperedges in each part together gives you $E$. The number of hyperedges incident on any particular node is definitely not 1, and can only be increased by the choice of refinement (note that the new edges in $E'$ need not be disjoint).

Comment: It may help to think about where this abstraction came from. We want to assign weights to every clique in a graph. $E$ is the set of maximal cliques. $E'$ is the set of cliques with nonzero weights.

Comment: Will an NP-hardness proof answer your question?

Comment: Listing maximal cliques is already NP hard (and even if you allow for output sensitivity the graph came from running a SAT solver $n^2$ times), so complexity classes are definitely not interesting to me (except maybe insofar as you can prove inapproximability).

Comment: Polynomially reducing it to some other solvable in practice NP hard problem, like integer linear programming, would be helpful (naive ILP doesn't work because there are exponentially many cliques)

Comment: Since the output is also of exponential size, designing an exponential time algorithm is the only option. Probably for any ILP, there will be an exponential number of variables. A more reasonable question perhaps could be finding an algorithm (or approximation algorithm) with running time polynomial in $|E|$. Otherwise, I believe, there are no practical solutions if the output is itself exponential.

Comment: Just an observation,:For this problem, there always exists an optimal solution that has $L(v) = 0$ for every vertex. So, maybe the second term in the optimization function can be removed and the constraint can be modified to $L(v)=0$ instead of $L(v)\geq 0 $. Not sure if it makes the problem easier.

Comment: Unfortunately any approach like that is too brittle to changes in the objective function for me; it would break if the objective function were $\lambda |E'| + |\{v \in V \mid L(v) > 0\}|$ for $\lambda \neq 1$, for example, which is probably closer to what I actually want to optimize. In general the thing I really want to optimize is probably closer to $f(E') + g(\{v \in V \mid L(v) > 0\})$ where $f$ and $g$ are submodular set functions, but a solution to the version with $\lambda$ would be a decent approximation in practice.